# autoindex_module does not work in php:apache?

Tags: php, docker, apache

I created a container that includes php:apache with Docker.
I want to use the environment to run a variety of PHP files and to try many things.

Access to a path with no index.* is denied for an error 403.
How can I activate autoindex and see the directory list?

http://localhost:8000/ returns this.

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Apache/2.4.56 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 8000
```

The container log is this.

```
Attaching to name
name  | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.26.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
name  | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.26.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
name  | [Sun May 28 06:45:53.417048 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.56 (Debian) PHP/8.2.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
name  | [Sun May 28 06:45:53.417105 2023] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
```

### Src

./docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  php:
    container_name: name
    image: php:apache
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./config/apache:/usr/local/apache2/conf
    ports:
      - 8000:80
```

./config/apache/httpd.conf

```
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
```

./src/phpinfo.php

```
<?php

phpinfo();
```

http://localhost:8000/phpinfo.php returns this.

```
PHP logo
PHP Version 8.2.6
System  Linux b2abb5b31a3e 5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Jan 27 02:56:13 UTC 2023 x86_64
Build Date  May 23 2023 09:41:46
Build System    Linux d4bc11463019 5.10.0-13-cloud-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.106-1 (2022-03-17) x86_64 GNU/Linux
Configure Command   './configure' '--build=x86_64-linux-gnu' '--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/etc/php' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d' '--enable-option-checking=fatal' '--with-mhash' '--with-pic' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-mysqlnd' '--with-password-argon2' '--with-sodium=shared' '--with-pdo-sqlite=/usr' '--with-sqlite3=/usr' '--with-curl' '--with-iconv' '--with-openssl' '--with-readline' '--with-zlib' '--disable-phpdbg' '--with-pear' '--with-libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--disable-cgi' '--with-apxs2' 'build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu'
Server API  Apache 2.0 Handler
Virtual Directory Support   disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /usr/local/etc/php
Loaded Configuration File   (none)
Scan this dir for additional .ini files /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed    /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sodium.ini
PHP API 20220829
PHP Extension   20220829
Zend Extension  420220829
Zend Extension Build    API420220829,NTS
PHP Extension Build API20220829,NTS
Debug Build no
Thread Safety   disabled
Zend Signal Handling    enabled
Zend Memory Manager enabled
Zend Multibyte Support  provided by mbstring
Zend Max Execution Timers   disabled
IPv6 Support    enabled
DTrace Support  disabled
Registered PHP Streams  https, ftps, compress.zlib, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar
Registered Stream Socket Transports tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, tls, tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2, tlsv1.3
Registered Stream Filters   zlib.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, convert.*, consumed, dechunk
Zend logoThis program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v4.2.6, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
Configuration
apache2handler
Apache Version  Apache/2.4.56 (Debian)
Apache API Version  20120211
Server Administrator    webmaster@localhost
Hostname:Port   172.24.0.3:80
User/Group  www-data(33)/33
Max Requests    Per Child: 0 - Keep Alive: on - Max Per Connection: 100
Timeouts    Connection: 300 - Keep-Alive: 5
Virtual Server  Yes
Server Root /etc/apache2
Loaded Modules  core mod_so mod_watchdog http_core mod_log_config mod_logio mod_version mod_unixd mod_access_compat mod_alias mod_auth_basic mod_authn_core mod_authn_file mod_authz_core mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_deflate mod_dir mod_env mod_filter mod_mime prefork mod_negotiation mod_php mod_reqtimeout mod_setenvif mod_status
Directive   Local Value Master Value
engine  On  On
last_modified   Off Off
xbithack    Off Off
Apache Environment
Variable    Value
HTTP_HOST   localhost:8000
HTTP_CONNECTION keep-alive
HTTP_SEC_CH_UA  "Google Chrome";v="113", "Chromium";v="113", "Not-A.Brand";v="24"
HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_MOBILE   ?0
HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_PLATFORM "Windows"
HTTP_DNT    1
HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS  1
HTTP_USER_AGENT Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
HTTP_ACCEPT text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE none
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_MODE navigate
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_USER ?1
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST document
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    gzip, deflate, br
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    ja,en;q=0.9
HTTP_COOKIE phpMyAdmin=4d288d3bece7895a9aad25518e619ca7; pma_lang=ja
PATH    /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
SERVER_SIGNATURE    <address>Apache/2.4.56 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 8000</address>
SERVER_SOFTWARE Apache/2.4.56 (Debian)
SERVER_NAME localhost
SERVER_ADDR 172.24.0.3
SERVER_PORT 8000
REMOTE_ADDR 172.24.0.1
DOCUMENT_ROOT   /var/www/html
REQUEST_SCHEME  http
CONTEXT_PREFIX  no value
CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT   /var/www/html
SERVER_ADMIN    webmaster@localhost
SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/phpinfo.php
REMOTE_PORT 52602
GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1
SERVER_PROTOCOL HTTP/1.1
REQUEST_METHOD  GET
QUERY_STRING    no value
REQUEST_URI /phpinfo.php
SCRIPT_NAME /phpinfo.php
HTTP Headers Information
HTTP Request Headers
HTTP Request    GET /phpinfo.php HTTP/1.1
Host    localhost:8000
Connection  keep-alive
sec-ch-ua   "Google Chrome";v="113", "Chromium";v="113", "Not-A.Brand";v="24"
sec-ch-ua-mobile    ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform  "Windows"
DNT 1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests   1
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
Sec-Fetch-Site  none
Sec-Fetch-Mode  navigate
Sec-Fetch-User  ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest  document
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language ja,en;q=0.9
Cookie  phpMyAdmin=4d288d3bece7895a9aad25518e619ca7; pma_lang=ja
HTTP Response Headers
X-Powered-By    PHP/8.2.6
```

### Attempt

I run these commands in `name` container.

```
# ls -la /var/www/html
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data  512 May 28 06:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root     root     4096 May 23 09:36 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data   17 May 28 04:31 phpinfo.php

# apachectl -M
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.26.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
```

./config/apache/httpd.conf

```
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</Directory>
```

./docker-compose.yml

```
    command:
      - apache2-foreground -D FOREGROUND
      - a2enmod autoindex
```

### Envs

- Windows 11 Home 22H2 22621.1778
- Docker 4.19.0 (106363)

Comment: What you present in your question all looks correct. What is your **specific** question? The autoindex module works in the php:apache image in general.

Answer (score 0):

In addition you need to allow indexing `Options +Indexes` [Options documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options), you may need to override this configuration when there is already global/default config by using `AllowOverride Options=Indexes` [AllowOverride documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I add the below to httpd.conf.
```
<Directory />
    Options +Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

However, I got this error.

`name  | [Wed May 31 01:45:59.840833 2023] [autoindex:error] [pid 19] [client 172.26.0.1:53470] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive`

Comment: `httpd.conf` was not included so I mounted it to `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/httpd.conf` and went well!